# Apache ignores Options -Indexes

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I want to disable Indexes server-wide. I tried the following:

In /etc/var/apache2/conf-available/security.conf:

```
<Directory />
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I know that security.conf is active, other directives in the file are working. But indexes are still shown.
Then I edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
Options -Indexes
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Doesn't work either. I have reloaded, stopped and started apache multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question is "Why does -Indexes not work?"

Check all files, you probably have more `<Directory ...` blocks in other files as well.

Easies to find these might be to `grep -r Options /etc/apache*` hopefully that finds the offender.

[Question about dumping configuration that could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943/how-can-i-view-the-complete-httpd-configuration)

Comment: Thank you! I found it with grep -r Indexes /etc/apache* in apache2.conf Now my "problem" is: I read everywhere that I shouldn't edit apache2.conf itself, because it will be overwritten by updates. But if I don't edit that line, directives elsewhere don't come into effect. What's a clean solution for that?